# MYSQL: change current id value become sequence id each day

Tags: mysql, sequence, concatenation

I want to show id value from the record below :

```
id      name            date
24811   Foo             2011-04-26
24812   Bar             2011-04-26
24813   Bars            2011-04-27
```

become this format:

```
date + Q + 4 digit ID sequence start from first ~ last
```

and the result is:

```
id              name            date
20110426Q0001   Foo             2011-04-26
20110426Q0002   Bar             2011-04-26
20110427Q0001   Bars            2011-04-27
```

But i'm just have a half query, how to make the 4 digit?

```
SELECT REPLACE( CONCAT( DATE( Inspection_datetime ) ,'Q',/*missing this query..*/),'-','') AS id,
       name,date
FROM mytable
```

after try answer below :

```
row @g:= `date`         id              Model           Serial      Lot_no  Inspection_datetime
1   2011-01-31 07:44:21 20110131Q0001   KW-HDR81BTJD    176X0099    010A    2011-01-31 07:44:21
1   2011-01-31 08:31:31 20110131Q0001   KW-HDR81BTJD    176X0098    010A    2011-01-31 08:31:31
1   2011-01-31 08:34:57 20110131Q0001   KW-HDR81BTJD    176X0065    010A    2011-01-31 08:34:57
1   2011-01-31 08:46:43 20110131Q0001   KW-HDR81BTJD    176X0050    010A    2011-01-31 08:46:43
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why both query from Khalid doesn't work in my `Mysql`.
Even I have tried at `sqlfiddle` it works but it doesn't in my database.
After a week i'm going crazy for this problem, i get the answer:

I'm using the second answer from Khalid then try to remove:

```
cross join (select @g=null, @r:= 0) t
```

then add before select:

```
set @g=null,@r:= 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You con do by using user defined variables

```
select 
@r:= case when @g = date then @r +1 else 1 end rownum,
@g:= date,
REPLACE( CONCAT( 
  DATE(date) ,
  'Q'
  ,lpad(@r,4,'0')
  ),'-','') AS id,
name,
date
from mytable
cross join (select @g=null, @r:= 0) t
order by date
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f43953/1)

If you are concerned to only the date part not the time part then you can do so

```
select 
@r:= case when @g = date(date) then @r +1 else 1 end rownum,
@g:= date(date),
REPLACE( CONCAT( 
  DATE(date) ,
  'Q'
  ,lpad(@r,4,'0')
  ),'-','') AS id,
name,
date
from mytable
cross join (select @g=null, @r:= 0) t
order by date
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/317204/4)

Comment: is it possible also for UPDATE ?

Comment: @nunu yes its possible by why you want to update id column ? leave it as it is and use select query if you want to show something as in the format in your question

Comment: @Khalid sometimes some id become too long if i set the column become autoincrement.

Comment: @nunu as you wish to you can update your table using similar logic in my answer

Comment: i've try it, but it seems not working in my actual database.please see my updated post.

Comment: @nunu thats why i have added the sample demo in my answer you can see it in action in sql fiddle don't know regarding your actual data i can't help

Comment: @Khalid i have tried in http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/317204/1, i put my data then i get wrong result.